# Compute the dimension of a 5x5 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix is given like this: all A(ii) entry= 1/2 while A(ij) entry= -A(ji) entry.
(In other words, all the diagonal entries of this 5x5 matrix is 1/2 and all the off-diagonals is A(ij) entry=-A(ji) entry

How to compute the dimension of this matrix? Appreciate your help!
thx!

Comment: Sorry is dimension typo

Comment: What do you mean by “dimension”? Is it the rank, perhaps?

Comment: @egreg ya is equivalent to rank!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Av=0$, for some vector $v$. If we show that $v=0$, then we know that $A$ has rank $5$.

Set $B=A-\frac{1}{2}I_5$ and observe that $B^T=-B$. Then, from $Av=0$, we get
$$
Bv=-\frac{1}{2}v.
$$
Multiply both sides by $v^T$:
$$
v^TBv=-\frac{1}{2}v^Tv.\tag{*}
$$
Transpose both sides:
$$
v^TB^Tv=-\frac{1}{2}v^Tv.
$$
Since $B^T=-B$, we get
$$
-v^TBv=-\frac{1}{2}v^Tv.\tag{**}
$$
Putting together (*) and (**), we get $v^TBv=-v^TBv$, which implies $v^TB^Tv=0$. Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{2}v^Tv=0
$$
which implies $v=0$.

Comment: Actually I have no idea of your explanation.I am learning Linear Algebra I , so any easier method to explain? would appreciate that!

Comment: @user3437854 I added the full solution, please look at it carefully. It's basically the proof that an antisymmetric matrix has purely imaginary eigenvalues.

Comment: erm, can you tell me what is the dimension you found?

Comment: @user3437854 It's written at the beginning! The null space of $A$ is $\{0\}$, so by the rank-nullity theorem the rank is $5$.

Comment: how do you get Bv=0.5v

Comment: and when you take the transpose, shouldnt the RHS be 0.5vv^T?

Comment: counting from last line, the third line should be v^TB^Tv=-v^TBv?

Comment: @user3437854 Yes, I forgot to remove the T

Comment: how about my other comments?true?

Comment: @user3437854 Certainly wrong: the transpose of $AB$ is $B^TA^T$, so the transpose of $v^Tv$ is $v^T(v^T)^T=v^Tv$: it's a $1\times 1$ matrix, by the way, so it *must* equal its transpose.

Comment: why isnt Bv= -0.5v the negative sign

Comment: @user3437854 You're right

Comment: thanks so much! I understand alrdy.Can vote for me ?xd